# SQL Inserting sum of values by part number into existing table

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, firebird2.5

I am trying to sum up the sales in the past year and store the total by part number in a new table. I have tried the code below, get no errors but usage remains empty. However i get the correct output if the first line (insert into) is not used.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_PARTS_MASTER (PNM_AUTO_KEY,USAGE)

  Select PNM_AUTO_KEY,sum(QTY_ORDERED)
    FROM so_detail
   WHERE ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN '2/23/2014' AND '2/23/2015'
GROUP BY PNM_AUTO_KEY
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the select as a subquery. something like this.

```
INSERT INTO TEST_PARTS_MASTER (PNM_AUTO_KEY,USAGE)

select * from (Select PNM_AUTO_KEY,sum(QTY_ORDERED)

FROM so_detail

WHERE ENTRY_DATE BETWEEN '2/23/2014' AND '2/23/2015'

GROUP BY PNM_AUTO_KEY)
```

Comment: Get an error token unknown for the (select...) after from. Also, PNM_AUTO_KEY contains more values in the test_parts_master than what is returned by the select request. I want to make sure they line up with the correct PNM_AUTO_KEY.